# getopt_long() fail when starting with non option character

Tags: c, getopt-long

This is my first program that uses getopt_long() so please excuse me if this questions is trivial.

I am having a problem when the first argument passed to my program is invalid

Here is my code for main

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  printf("----------------------------------------------\n\n");

  int fd[128];
  int fdCount=0;

  int c;
  int digit_optind =0;
  int verboseFlag=0;

  //to exit with this specific value collected from all functions
  int overallExitStatus=0;

  while(1)
    {

      int this_option_optind = optind ? optind : 1;
      int option_index =0;

      static struct option long_options[] = {

        {"rdonly",     optional_argument, 0,   'a'},
        {"wronly",     optional_argument, 0,   'b'},
        {"command",    optional_argument, 0,   'c'},
        {"verbose",    no_argument,       0,   'd'},
        {0,0,0,0}

      };
      c=getopt_long(argc,argv, "+", long_options, &option_index);

      if(c == -1)
        break;

      switch(c) {
      case 'a':
        rdonly(fd,&fdCount,verboseFlag,&optind,argc,argv);
        break;

      case 'b':
        wronly(fd,&fdCount,verboseFlag,&optind,argc,argv);
        break;

      case 'c':
        overallExitStatus +=command(fd,&optind,optarg,argc,argv,verboseFlag);
        break;

      case 'd':
        verboseFlag=1;
        break;

      case '?':
        break;

      default:
        printf("?? getopt returned character code 0%o ??\n", c);
      }
    }

   printf("Program is finished exiting with status %d\n",overallExitStatus);
  printf("----------------------------------------------\n\n");

  return overallExitStatus;
}
```

basically if I start my program in the following way

./myProgram a --rdonly file1.txt

the program does not parse trough any arguments, skips the switch and goes straight to return.

in a case when the first argument starts with - or -- (even if it is a wrong argument) the program behaves correctly.

How can I fix this issue ?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`a` is a valid non-option (positional) argument, so that's what getopt_long assumes it is.

The `+` in the getopt_long options string prevents reordering of option arguments, so it doesn't look ahead to the `--rdonly` argument. Even if you had allowed reordering, the `a` would be treated as the first positional argument.